# Custom PAM for SSHD in C

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, ssh, pam

I am trying to understand how PAM works by creating an SSH backdoor. Following this example https://github.com/beatgammit/simple-pam I already know how to make a functional PAM module, but I want to read a hardcode token from the CIN. I tried the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <security/pam_appl.h>
#include <security/pam_modules.h>

/* expected hook */
PAM_EXTERN int pam_sm_setcred( pam_handle_t *pamh, int flags, int argc, const char **argv ) {
    return PAM_SUCCESS;
}

PAM_EXTERN int pam_sm_acct_mgmt(pam_handle_t *pamh, int flags, int argc, const char **argv) {
    printf("Acct mgmt\n");
    return PAM_SUCCESS;
}

/* expected hook, this is where custom stuff happens */
PAM_EXTERN int pam_sm_authenticate( pam_handle_t *pamh, int flags,int argc, const char **argv ) {
    int retval;

    const char* pUsername;
    retval = pam_get_user(pamh, &pUsername, "Username: ");

    printf("Welcome %s\n", pUsername);

    if (retval != PAM_SUCCESS) {
        return retval;
    }

    if (strcmp(pUsername, "luciannitescu") != 0) {
        return PAM_AUTH_ERR;
    }

    char securetoken[8] = "aaaaaaa";
    char password[8];
    printf("Enter your secure token:\n");
    scanf(password);

    if (strcmp(password, securetoken) != 0)
    {
        return PAM_AUTH_ERR;
    }
    return PAM_SUCCESS;
}
```

When performing an ssh authentification I am receiving the permission denied message and if I remove the following lines of code everything is working:

```
char securetoken[8] = "aaaaaaa";
    char password[8];
    printf("Enter your secure token:\n");
    scanf(password);

    if (strcmp(password, securetoken) != 0)
    {
        return PAM_AUTH_ERR;
    }
```

Failed authentification:

```
ssh luciannitescu@127.0.0.1 -v
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 127.0.0.1 [127.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/lucian/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/lucian/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/lucian/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/lucian/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/lucian/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/lucian/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/lucian/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/lucian/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 127.0.0.1:22 as 'luciannitescu'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:...
debug1: Host '127.0.0.1' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/lucian/.ssh/known_hosts:22
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:... /home/lucian/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/lucian/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/lucian/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/lucian/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
luciannitescu@127.0.0.1's password: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
luciannitescu@127.0.0.1's password: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
luciannitescu@127.0.0.1's password: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
luciannitescu@127.0.0.1: Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

**Later edit:**

After changing the code with the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <security/pam_appl.h>
#include <security/pam_modules.h>

/* expected hook */
PAM_EXTERN int pam_sm_setcred( pam_handle_t *pamh, int flags, int argc, const char **argv ) {
    return PAM_SUCCESS;
}

PAM_EXTERN int pam_sm_acct_mgmt(pam_handle_t *pamh, int flags, int argc, const char **argv) {
    printf("Acct mgmt\n");

    return PAM_SUCCESS;
}

/* expected hook, this is where custom stuff happens */
PAM_EXTERN int pam_sm_authenticate( pam_handle_t *pamh, int flags,int argc, const char **argv ) {
    struct pam_message msg[1];
    struct pam_response *resp = NULL;
    struct pam_conv *conv;

    pam_get_item (pamh, PAM_CONV, (const void **) &conv);
    msg[0].msg = "Enter your secret token: ";
    msg[0].msg_style = PAM_PROMPT_ECHO_OFF;
    conv->conv(1, &msg, &resp, conv->appdata_ptr);
    // Token is now in resp->resp;

    int retval;

    const char* pUsername;
    retval = pam_get_user(pamh, &pUsername, "Username: ");

    printf("Welcome %s\n", pUsername);

    if (retval != PAM_SUCCESS) {
        return retval;
    }

    if (strcmp(pUsername, "luciannitescu") != 0) {
        return PAM_AUTH_ERR;
    }



    return PAM_SUCCESS;
}
```

I am unable to make an SSH connection:

```
lucian@local:~$ ssh luciannitescu@127.0.0.1
luciannitescu@127.0.0.1's password: 
Connection closed by 127.0.0.1 port 22
```

Server Debug:

```
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 23
debug2: userauth_pubkey: authenticated 0 pkalg rsa-sha2-512 [preauth]
debug3: userauth_finish: failure partial=0 next methods="publickey,password" [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 51 [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 50 [preauth]
debug1: userauth-request for user luciannitescu service ssh-connection method password [preauth]
debug1: attempt 2 failures 1 [preauth]
debug2: input_userauth_request: try method password [preauth]
debug3: mm_auth_password entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 12 [preauth]
debug3: mm_auth_password: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_AUTHPASSWORD [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 13 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 12
debug3: PAM: sshpam_passwd_conv called with 1 messages
mm_log_handler: write: Broken pipe
debug1: do_cleanup
debug3: PAM: sshpam_thread_cleanup entering
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `scanf()` to read a value from the user, since stdin is not passed to the user. You have to use ssh keyboard-interactive authentication with the appropriate functions. This is supported by the **pam_conv** (PAM conversation) functions.

The manpage _man 3 pam_conv_ describes the interface. It works basically like this:

```
PAM_EXTERN int
pam_sm_authenticate (pam_handle_t * pamh,
                 int flags, int argc, const char **argv)
{
    struct pam_message msg[1];
    struct pam_response *resp = NULL;
    struct pam_conv *conv;

    pam_get_item (pamh, PAM_CONV, (const void **) &conv);
    msg[0].msg = "Enter your secret token: ";
    msg[0].msg_style = PAM_PROMPT_ECHO_OFF;
    conv->conv(1, &msg, &resp, conv->appdata_ptr);
    // Token is now in resp->resp;
    ....
}
```

You can use this as a start for your custom authentication function.

Comment: why do I get a connection closed on port 22?

Comment: @NitescuLucian If you have additional issues, please describe them in your question in detail.

Comment: @NitescuLucian 1) Always do error-checking (pam_get_item()/conv->conv()) etc. I have omitted that for sake of brevity. Furthermore, you can start your server with `sshd -dddDp 222` and connect to port 222 and see what happens on the server side.

Comment: could you help me?